# google scripts search calendar by variable

Tags: javascript, search, google-apps-script, calendar

I would like to find events in google calendar based on a variable (that variable will be sent in a dialog box in the final version).

It would be something like this:

```
var texts = "word_to_find";
var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("January 1, 2010 00:00:00 CST"), new Date("January 1, 2020 23:59:59 CST"), {search: '+texts+'});
```

So texts is a variable to receive the needed search term (here is word_to_find).
The syntax is wrong because +texts+ is not replaced by the value of the variable texts at running time.

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: Review string concatenation in JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
'+texts+'
```

use

```
texts
```

For further details check out the JavaScript documentation about using variables, like [Storing the information you need — Variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Variables)